# running npm install throws permission error

Tags: node.js, sockets

Following these directions to install nodeJs and socketIO on a Raspberry Pi

```
http://www.bartbania.com/index.php/build-your-own-google-tv-using-raspberrypi/
```

When I try running

```
npm install
```

get the following error

```
Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
```

Prefixing with 'sudo' simply gives a 'command not found'

Anyone know how to resolve this?

I tried to recursively change the owner of the files in my /usr/local folder to the current user:

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local
```

But it makes no difference

Comment: sudo /opt/node/bin/npm install  Yes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking over the link you provided, the likely problem is that the environment variable JS_HOME is set for the pi user (or whatever user you installed node as) but not for root.

The simpleset way to fix this is to use the full path to the npm commnad. To determine what the proper path is type

```
which npm
```

in the terminal. this will return the full path. Then you can do

```
sudo <full path to npm> install...
```

Since the above fixed the problem you may not have set the path correctly in /etc/profile.

```
sudo nano /etc/profile
```

Add the following lines to the file before the ‘export’ command.

```
NODE_JS_HOME="/opt/node"
PATH="$PATH:$NODE_JS_HOME/bin"
export PATH
```

You may need to logout for the above to take effect. You can verify that it works by using the following command:

echo $PATH

If you correct that you won't need to use the full path.

You probably also want to reverse the change of ownership for usr/local as well by typing.

```
sudo chown -R root /usr/local
```

Answer (score -1):

Try reinstalling pre-compiled node package:

```
wget http://node-arm.herokuapp.com/node_latest_armhf.deb
sudo dpkg -i node_latest_armhf.deb
```

and run npm again

Comment: The problem is not with the install, but with his $PATH variable.